# javascript or beanshell not executing in xml

Tags: jmeter

I have placed javaScript and beanshell script in XML , when I copy paste the xml in the request text area it executes both ( JavaScript and beanshell) but when I am trying to use `${__FileToString(${__eval(${fileName})},,)}` where file-name is the path of my XML its note executing the scripts inside the XML.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work that way, __eval() function does not execute scripts. Consider using [__BeanShell()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) or [__JavaScript](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) functions instead like:

- `${__BeanShell(${__FileToString(${fileName},,)};,)}`
- `${__javaScript(${__FileToString(${fileName},,)};,)}`

You won't be able to combine BeanShell and JavaScript in single file as they're processed with different interpreters and languages are not compatible so you will have to refactor your scripts and and in general it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for any scripting. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for comprehensive explanation, groovy scripting engine installation guidelines and scripting best practices